# Add property to xml using xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I have the following base XML

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <mapping class="com.model.Menu"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

That same base XML **can contain** some properties or not, for example:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <mapping class="com.model.Menu"/>
    <property name="driver_class">some-class</property>
    <property name="driver_dialect">some-dialect</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Now i need to use xmlstarlet to insert those properties if they do not exist or update those values if they do exist without creating any duplicates. I know how to update and also know how to insert, but since i do not know in advance if those properties exist or not I have no idea how i can do that.

What would be the correct way of doing that ?

Answer (score 1):

Use XPath expressions to specify the 'update-or-add-if-not-exists'
condition:

```sh
xmlstarlet edit \
  --var T '/hibernate-configuration/session-factory' \
  -u '$T/property[@name="driver_class"]' -v 'some_class' \
  -s '$T[not(property[@name="driver_class"])]' -t elem -n 'property' -v 'some_class' \
  -s '$prev' -t attr -n 'name' -v 'driver_class' \
  …
file.xml
```

where:

- `-u …` (aka `--update`) executes only if the specified node exists
- the two `-s …` (aka `--subnode`) execute only if no such node exists:
  if the first `-s …` matches nothing then `-s '$prev' …` will match
  nothing

`--var` defines a named variable, and the back reference `$prev`
variable (aka `$xstar:prev`) refers to the node(s) created by the most
recent `-s`, `-i`, or `-a` option which all define or redefine it
(see [`xmlstarlet.txt`](https://fossies.org/linux/xmlstarlet/doc/xmlstarlet.txt)
for examples of `--var` and `$prev`).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any "insert or update", or any xmlstarlet subcommands that are conditionals. Presumably you want to use xmlstarlet so you don't have to write XSLT.

This is the best I could come up with: the `sel` subcommand returns a non-zero exit status if the xpath does not exist in the document.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

xpath_root="/hibernate-configuration/session-factory"

set_property() {
    local file=$1 name=$2 value=$3
    local xpath="$xpath_root/property[@name = '$name']"
    local tmpfile=$(mktemp)

    if xmlstarlet sel -t -v "$xpath" "$file" >/dev/null
    then
        # property exists, alter it
        xmlstarlet ed -O -u "$xpath" -v "$value" "$file"

    else
        # property does not exists, add it
        xmlstarlet ed -O \
            -s "$xpath_root" -t elem -n "property" -v "$value" \
            -a "$xpath_root/property[not(@name)]" -t attr -n "name" -v "$name" \
            "$file"

    fi > "$tmpfile" && mv "$tmpfile" "$file"
}

for file in base1.xml base2.xml; do
    cp "$file" "$file.bak"
    set_property "$file" driver_class "new class"
    set_property "$file" driver_dialect "new dialect"
done
```

After running the script

```bash
$ diff base1.xml{.bak,}
3a4,5
>     <property name="driver_class">new class</property>
>     <property name="driver_dialect">new dialect</property>
```

and

```bash
$ diff base2.xml{.bak,}
4,5c4,5
<     <property name="driver_class">some-class</property>
<     <property name="driver_dialect">some-dialect</property>
---
>     <property name="driver_class">new class</property>
>     <property name="driver_dialect">new dialect</property>
```